# switch between two main forms in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have tried this [answer](http://goo.gl/bGiql5) for the same problem but in this line

```
LoginSucceeded := flogin.Successful;
```

I get the following error:

> undeclared identifier successful

How to fix it?

Comment: Declare `Successful` and make it report the appropriate value

Answer (score 3):

In your login form, create a boolean property `Successful` that defines the state of the login upon completion.

```
Type
  TLoginForm = class(TForm)
  ...
  procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    FSuccessful: Boolean;
  public 
    property Successful: Boolean read FSuccessful write FSuccessful;
  end;

procedure TLoginForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Successful := "Enter your condition of successful login here";
end;
```

Comment: why not use the modalresult property of the form? a login form is normally modal...

Comment: @whosrdaddy, yes using `ModalResult` is an option (which I'm using most of the time). But there is a value in knowing how to transfer information from modal dialogs. I mean, suppose you wanted to know which user was logging in, then just add a property with the user name, etc. In more complex cases a record could be used. Anyway, the answer was focused on the question asked.